# Disable manual column editing (input from keyboard) with phpexcel

Tags: phpexcel

Here I have a case where I want to make a column to be editable by choosing value through drop-down only so user is not able to edit it manually by typing anything.

Do you have any solution for this by using PHPExcel?

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Wondering once again what is the point of writing documentation: [Setting Security on a Spreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#setting-security-on-a-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 0):

I have accomplish this task by using following code.

```
                   $objValidation = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B'.$i)->getDataValidation();
                    $objValidation->setType( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST );
                    $objValidation->setErrorStyle( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION );
                    $objValidation->setAllowBlank(false);
                    $objValidation->setShowInputMessage(true);
                    $objValidation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
                    $objValidation->setShowDropDown(true);
                    $objValidation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
                    $objValidation->setError('Value is not in list.');
                    $objValidation->setPromptTitle('Pick from list');
                    $objValidation->setPrompt('Please pick a value from the drop-down list.');
                    $objValidation->setFormula1('"Rate,Margin"');
```